# Append Values in Column from Table to Table In Kusto Control Command

Tags: azure-data-explorer

If I have table A that has a column of `Student Id`, and I have table B that also has `Student Id` Column, what's the control command that to copy all values of `Student Id` from Table A to Table B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.set student2 <| print StudentID = "12345", StudentAddress = "MyLane, Mycity"

.set student1 <| print StudentID = "12345", StudentName = "John"

.set   tmp <| student1 | join kind=inner student2 on StudentID | project-away StudentID1

.drop table student1

.set student1 <| tmp

.drop table tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

To Append values from **TableA** to **TableB** in kusto you can use **`.set-or-append`**,  it will update **TableB** with the data present in **TableA** as shown in the below query:

Data Stored in TableA:
[image]

Data stored in TableB:
[image]

```sql
.set-or-append TableB <| TableA
```

**Output:**
[image]

For more information click this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query).